# Using Asp.net how to open outlook at the client system and load multiple attachments?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Please suggest me the way to attach the multiple files from file-up-loader control from asp.net. On click of button I should attach these files and show them in outlook before sending mails to multiple people. I'm using multiple file-up-loader for multiple files.

Regarding this i searched many places and i got 3 ways.

1. Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook dll. But it does not work on
   client side.As this dll will try to open outlook on the server side.
2. Using Mailto in hyperlink.But using this i'm not able to attach files.
3. Using SMTP.i.e using System.Net dll. But with this i can send mails to the intended people,but i need to open outlook before sending mails,as this is my requirement.

Suggest me the way to open outlook with multiple attachments at client side on click of a button.

Answer (score 2):

Simply stated if you're from outside the local network environment, you can't.

You can, when inside a local network, attach files to the mailto link using the full UNC path (including the server, which should be available to the user), but otherwise there is no way to open outlook including your attachment.

And to be honest, we should be happy that you cannot auto-attach a virus laden file using my own e-mail program of choice to redistribute at my own leisure...